# Is it possible to get no stars on a cup in Mario Kart 7?

Tags: mario-kart-7

I have had a 2-star rank for all my cups, and have found out the Gold Wheels required all cups with a 1-star rank (at least). Is it actually possible to get no stars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to get no stars.  The ranks, in descending order, are 3 stars, 2 stars, 1 star, A, B, C, D and E.